# Upgrading to Rails 3: Problem to define the root page

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-3-upgrade

I have a problem to set the home page of my application.

My rails2 route:

```
map.login   'login',  :controller => 'user_sessions', :action => 'new'
map.root :login
```

My rails3 route:

```
match 'login', :to => 'user_sessions#new', :as => 'login'
root :to => :login
```

But "root :to => :login" give me this error:

```
No route matches "/"
```

And with:

```
root :to => 'users_sessions#new'
```

I have this error:

```
uninitialized constant UsersSessionsController
```

I can not figure out where this error.
Does anyone have any idea?

Thx, have a good day

Michaël

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `root :to =>` needs to point to a string in the format of `controller#action` like your second example, not a symbol.

Also, you typed "users_sessions" instead of "user_sessions". This should work:

```
root :to => 'user_sessions#new'
```